Cut 1/8 inch off the metal hinge running the length of a shower door
I am replacing an old grungy shower door with a lightly used one that is just shy of 1/8" too wide to fit in the enclosure.

After studying the situation for a while the best solution I am coming up with is to reduce the hinge side by 1/8". There is nothing stopping that from being done but it will be tricky to do the actual cut. I would be thinking to use a cutoff wheel. It will be two long difficult cuts that would then need to be filed down.  It's likely to take time and not be perfect.
Any thoughts on how to go about this - either with the cutoff wheel and some kind of guide or in some other fashion?

A vise and and an angle grinder will be a few minutes for 1/8 of a hinge.   You do want a vise/clamp to hold the hinge, which ever way you go.

Can you add an annotated closeup? It’s not obvious to me what you want to trim.

@AloysiusDefenestrate The green rectangle is showing a section of the metal to be cut .   The entire length would be cut

@crip659 perhaps a grinder disc in a table saw?  That way there's a fence/guide to keep the amount of cutoff consistent.

@Huesmann  A table saw setup would be the most accurate: but I do not have a large platform on mine and the door itself is about 100 pounds.

@WestCoastProjects, well, I was assuming the glass could be removed from the hinge...running a whole door through a table saw seems like begging for it to shatter into a million pieces.

In the abstract (because I still don’t understand exactly what is getting trimmed) a coarse flap wheel on an angle grinder would be my choice to shrink aluminum. If that aluminum is still attached to a glass door, you need to be extra careful about vibrations that lead to shattering.
